# Function in R which returns ancestors and children in a network

Tags: r, networking, children, ancestor

I would like to create a function "f" in R which has in entry a data.frame of edges between individuals and an individual (called A2 for instance) and which returns another data.frame with only "ancestors" and "children" of A2 and also ancestors of ancestors and children of children !

To illustrate my complicated issue :

```
 library(visNetwork)
 nodes <- data.frame(id = c(paste0("A",1:5),paste0("B",1:3)),
                label = c(paste0("A",1:5),paste0("B",1:3)))
 edges <- data.frame(from = c("A1","A1","A2","A3","A4","B1","B2"),
                to = c("A2","A3","A4","A4","A5","B3","B3"))
 visNetwork(nodes, edges) %>% 
   visNodes(font = list(size=45)) %>% 
    visHierarchicalLayout(direction = "LR", levelSeparation = 500)
```

[image]

In this example, the data.frame contains 2 different independant networks : 1 network with "A"s and another with "B"s.

I would like to implement a function f(data=edges, indiv="A2") which returns a data.frame which contains all lines of data.frame edges concerned with the network of "A"s :

f(edges,"A2") would return this extract of data.frame edges

```
 head(f(edges,"A2"))
 #  from to
 #1   A1 A2
 #2   A1 A3
 #3   A2 A4
 #4   A3 A4
 #5   A4 A5
```

I hope it is clear enough for you to help me.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: What have you tried? What is the algorithm you are trying to implement?

Comment: Not sure to understand exactly what you want but the goal is in fact to return for each individual it's ancestors and children and the children of their children and ancestors of ancestors. And before spending time (certainly hours) to code it i wanted to know if there is a well known function / package to do it because it seems to me that it could be a quite basic question for people (unlike me) who are used to work with networks. But i didn't find something satisfying on the internet yet (only for trees) so i wanted to ask more specialist people about it  ! Thanks

Comment: I'm not a graph analyst, but maybe this could help :  http://igraph.org/r/doc/components.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written a simple algorithm to find all the family linked to an individual (and I’m sure it can be improved).  Like @romles suggested you can do the same thing with some R packages like igraph. However, in this case, my function seems a bit more performant that the igraph option.

```
edges <- data.frame(from = c("A1","A1","A2","A3","A4","B1","B2"),
                    to = c("A2","A3","A4","A4","A5","B3","B3"),
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
f <- function(data, indiv){
    children_ancestors <- function(indiv){
        # Find children and ancestors of an indiv
        c(data[data[,"from"]==indiv,"to"],data[data[,"to"]==indiv,"from"])
    }
    family <- indiv
    new_people <- children_ancestors(indiv) # New people to inspect
    while(length(diff_new_p <- setdiff(new_people,family)) > 0){
        # if the new people aren't yet in the family :
        family <- c(family, diff_new_p)
        new_people <- unlist(sapply(diff_new_p, children_ancestors))
        new_people <- unique(new_people)
    }
    data[(data[,1] %in% family) | (data[,2] %in% family),]
}
```

`f(edges, "A2")` gives the expected result. Comparing to the igraph function:

```
library(igraph)
library(microbenchmark)
edges2 <- graph_from_data_frame(edges, directed = FALSE)
microbenchmark(simple_function = f(edges,"A2"),
               igraph_option = as_data_frame(subgraph.edges(edges2, subcomponent(edges2, 'A2', 'in')))
               )
#Unit: microseconds
#            expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
# simple_function  874.411  968.323 1206.037 1123.515 1325.075 2957.931   100
#   igraph_option 1239.896 1451.364 1802.341 1721.227 1984.380 3907.089   100
```

Comment: Thank you to the three of you for your answers, all very useful to understand the algorithm I need and the igraph package. I will take time to understand all the solutions you offered !

Answer (score 2):

You could try and filter only the nodes that are connected to A2 (i.e. distance is not equal to `Inf`

```
library(tidygraph)
edges <- data.frame(from = c("A1","A1","A2","A3","A4","B1","B2"),
                    to = c("A2","A3","A4","A4","A5","B3","B3"))
as_tbl_graph(edges) %>% 
  filter(is.finite(node_distance_to(name=="A2", mode="all")))
```

which gives

```
# A tbl_graph: 5 nodes and 5 edges
#
# A directed acyclic simple graph with 1 component
#
# Node Data: 5 x 1 (active)
   name
  <chr>
1    A1
2    A2
3    A3
4    A4
5    A5
#
# Edge Data: 5 x 2
   from    to
  <int> <int>
1     1     2
2     1     3
3     2     4
# ... with 2 more rows
```

Comment: Thank you to the three of you for your answers, all very useful to understand the algorithm I need and the igraph package. I will take time to understand all the solutions you offered !

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
library(igraph)
g <- graph_from_literal(A1--A2, A1--A3, A2--A4, A3--A4, A4--A5, B1--B3, B2--B3 )
sg_a2 <- subcomponent(g, 'A2', 'in')
as_data_frame(subgraph.edges(g, sg_a2))
```

It gives:

```
#  from to
#1   A1 A2
#2   A1 A3
#3   A2 A4
#4   A3 A4
#5   A4 A5
```

Comment: Thank you to the three of you for your answers, all very useful to understand the algorithm I need and the igraph package. I will take time to understand all the solutions you offered !